# Windows CE centralized message queue between processes

Tags: c++, winapi, events, windows-ce, message-queue

Setup:  4 processes need to monitor a centralized source (I am thinking Message Queue) and be alerted when a message is put into the queue. This is for reporting errors that each process needs to know about to decide what they individually will do about it.

I have a few questions however, since I want to make sure Message Queues are the best way to go about it before I venture to far down that road.

Does the Message Queue API on Windows CE have events/notifications of some sort? If not, does the Windows CE OS itself allow you to tie in to the queue somehow for alerts of new messages arriving?  Is there a better Inter Process communication tool for this kind of setup and requirements?

EDIT: Also, this will be a running log of errors that cant be lost, so I will put it on my flash memory.

Answer (score 0):

What always works is a simple TCP connection via loopback. This also makes it easy to debug on a desktop system, in case you want. Concerning CE's message queues, those are always 1:1, so you'd need as many as you have connections between processes. Also, if you want to use them in a TCP stream-like manner, you'll need one for each direction.

There is another way you could use, and that is to monitor the file that you're logging the info to. I'm not sure to what extent CE supports a notification API for file changes, but if you don't need low-latency reactions, you can always poll every now-and-then. Alternatively, use a named event after writing to the logfile.

Comment: Found out that CE does support NAMED events. Being new-ish in the realm of winAPI and embedded, I did not realized having a named event meant other processes could hook into the global event and use that. It didn't say anything in the documentation on MSDN about the consequence of naming or not naming an event. After finding this out on some researching, I am going the named event route.

Comment: There are other such global resources like mutexes and shared memory, exactly to provide IPC functions. Good luck!